# can i query Cloudant NOSQL data base for specific data?

Tags: database, cloudant, nosql

"data": {
    "d": [
      100,
      0,
      1,
      1,
      0,
      22,
      55,
      66,
      99,
      87
    ]
this is my data format on Cloudant NOSql Database each integer inside array "d" corresponds to specific parameter values from device, is it possible to query only the required data(may be 100) which correspond to specific parameter, from the array?

Comment: Do you mean you want to always query the first element of the array -- i.e. d[0]?

Comment: yes i want to query the first element of the array "d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view with this map function, which returns all documents that have the value `100` in the first index of the array `data.d`:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.data && doc.data.d && doc.data.d.length>0 && doc.data.d[0] == 100)
    emit([doc._id,doc.data.d[0]], 1);
}
```

Here's a query listing a sample database containing 3 data rows and 1 design document containing the above map function:

```
https://rajsingh.cloudant.com/aaa/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

And here's the query that returns only the documents meeting the view constraints:

```
https://rajsingh.cloudant.com/aaa/_design/views/_view/dzero?limit=200&reduce=false&include_docs=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but what I *think* you want is to create a view with a map function that looks like this:

```js
function(doc) {
  doc.data.d.map(function(parameter) {
    emit(parameter);
  });
}
```

This would allow you to, for example, search for the parameter value `22` and find all documents with this parameter value.

Comment: The parameter values keeps changing since these are sensor values, i should query the position of the value (d[0] or d[5]), to get the corresponding data from the cloudant database, now i'am fetching the entire array of above given data.my requirement is to query particular position and get the data